# Not able to open the website from new webserver. It is pointing to the older one

Tags: php, apache, dns, webserver, hosting

I changed the nameserver of my domain so that it should point to the new hosting server. Now on my mobile, I can open the website hosted on the new webserver but on my laptop I can still open the older one (the website hosted on older web server). I cleared its dns caching by:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

but its not working. Do, I need to perform some extra steps?

Note: My website is in PHP, MYSQL with Apache Server.

Answer (score 1):

Wait up to a day easily. How long have you waited, it can take an hour at least. Is the mobile connected to the same router as your laptop? or perhaps using mobile data.

I suggest you get the address for a different DNS, and force your Operative system to use it. You can choose whatever, but OpenDNS (opendns.com/setupguide/?url=familyshield) might work, configure your system to use it (if windows at network options, same place where you can change your internal ip).

Comment: My moblie is connected to my personal 4G internet. But, laptop is connected to company's internet.

Comment: Then your company's ISP or even router if it serves dns data must be caching the site, the test with the mobile doesn't count because it goes through a different provider who just got its first call for that site or is just faster at updating.

Comment: Then what's the next step. How can I remove caching from the ISP?

Comment: I suggest you get the address for a different DNS, and force your Operative system to use it. You can choose whatever, but OpenDNS might work, configure your system to use it (if windows at network options, same place where you can change your internal ip).

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes on your DNS records, you should wait 24 hours for the propagation of your changes. The DNS propagation is the time taken for the domain DNS to refresh the cache on the entire network. You can't force DNS to refresh faster at this time. When your website is live, you can change the update time, by changing `TTL` (which is set by default on most, to 24 hours) to a lower number, but this won't be really helpful on all networks, because some of them may update at a slower rate.

**If there are over 24 hours after changing DNS and you're not able to see the website on the new server, then you should try to flush DNS on your computer, like this:**

**Windows**:

Open command prompt and run:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

**Linux (depending on versions and distros)**:

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

OR

```
service nscd reload
```

**Mac (there are multiple methods, depending on versions)**

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

For older versions of Mac, check their support https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516

If you have a router on the network, please restart the router. If the router has its own dns cache, depending on your router model, open the firmware and find clear/flush dns cache option (read router documentation before).

Your mobile phone most probably used the mobile network, which is not the same which your computer used.

To be sure you have corectly changed your nameservers and to view the TTL (Time To Live) of your nameservers (how long it takes until updating dns on the networks), you can use our tool: http://netcreator.us/dns-propagation-check

Answer (score 0):

Generally DNS propagation takes time upto 48 hrs to take affect globally. When we working on the URL for longer time then it usually a cache problem, Flushing DNS sometimes won't work. Wait for few hrs and it will get it fix automatically. These are some of the things you could quickly try to get connect and see the newer version is live and working properly.

Try restarting your computer and connect to internet, if possible try from different browser.

Try http://network-tools.com and see whether the domain is pointing to new hosting IP address.

Try http://hide.me/proxy/ and enter URL, it will show you the live and updated version of your website OR domain.